# datetime is not function with jquery 1.12

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

However, it keeps saying that:

> TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Can you help me find my error ?

Comment: Have you included jquery.ui,js?

Comment: Hi Thangaraja , that was indeed the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date picker is from jQuery UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Which you have not included

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/